# Windows Forms app cannot find default database

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, winforms, ado.net

I know this question is somewhat general but maybe someone can give me some general ideas as to the answer to my problem:
Scenerio:  Winform vb.net application that has been maintained for 20 years (origins are in .net beta).  Many of the connection strings are:  Data Source=myserver;Integrated Security=True;
The program has had no problem finding the default database from the server for these 20 years until now.
After upgrading the SQL Server to version 2022, my production machine no longer recognizes my default database as default and thus I get the error "Cannot find myobject".  Of course if I correct the connection string to :  Data Source=myserver;Initial Catalog=mydb;Integrated Security=True;  to solve the problem.  Another 'weird' tidbit is that so far this only occurs on my development box and not on any of the clients using the program.
Before I go through the tedious task of correcting all the connection strings, I was wondering if anyone has any ideas what causes the problem.

Comment: Just a question. Why do you have to correct many connection strings? It seems like you have the connection strings inside hard coded instead of storing just one connectionstring in the appropriate _ConnectionStrings_ configuration section of your config file and let your code read this key/value when needed.

Comment: 2022 is still in preview; have you really upgraded to that?

Comment: As for the problem, seems like you didn't define the default database to your application's for the `LOGIN`s; though I would suggest you define the database in the connection string anyway rather than relying on the default database connection.

Comment: One does not simply upgrade to SQL Server 2022. It seems like the Windows Logon needs to have its default database property set/corrected on the new SQL Server. Ref: [ALTER LOGIN (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-login-transact-sql), or you could just fix it through the SSMS > Server > Security > Logins GUI. But you should probably pay the price now and specify the inital catalog in the connection strings so as to avoid a repeat of the problem down the road.

Comment: All the 'newer' code (10 years and newer) uses the connection strings in the app.config file.  The older code is all over the place, some in the settings file and some apparently hardcoded in designers and I have to go into each designer and see if the connection is hard coded or not.

Comment: Can you tell me where I define the application's LOGINs?

Comment: Thank you very much AlwaysLearning.  You taught me something new.  That was exactly the problem.  I'll start fixing connection strings also but I can do it now at a slower pace.

Comment: Just to answer Lamu.  I don't upgrade versions often and I find it best to upgrade to the latest version that's available even if I have to survive a few bugs.  I started this application in .NET beta and though I suffered somewhat in the beginning I'm glad I did or I would be stuck now with a VB6 application with 0 support.

Comment: Try this Nuget library : nuget.org/packages/Ado.Entity